# spring autowired repository null when instancing an object

Tags: spring-boot

I have come accross this problem quite a few times and still being confused about it

I create an object "Portfolio" through BeanFactory as the object might have several instance.

I have an entity "PortfolioState" inside portfolio which I need to initialize from the database.

Doing so return errors as the portfolioStateRepository is null. I can have it added in the constructor but the way I am looking at this seems really odd to carry the repository like that.

I am feeling I am missing completely the point to initialize the portfolioState inside a new object Portfolio if I need to carry my repository with me. Please help.

```
    @Component
    public class PortfolioFactory {
        
            private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        
            @Autowired
            public PortfolioFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
            }
        
            public synchronized Portfolio createPortfolio(int portfolioId) {
                final Portfolio portfolio = (Portfolio) applicationContext.getBean("Portfolio",portfolioId);
                return portfolio;
            }
        }


    @Configuration
    public class PortfolioFactoryConfig {
    
        @Bean(name = "Portfolio")
        @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
        public Portfolio createPortfolio(int portfolioId) {
            return new Portfolio(portfolioId);
        }
    }

@Data
public class Portfolio {

    @Autowired
    PortfolioStateRepository portfolioStateRepository;
    private PortfolioState portfolioState;

    public Portfolio(Integer portfolioId){
        if(portfolioState==null){
            if(portfolioStateRepository.findByPortfolioId(portfolioId).isPresent()){
                this.portfolioState = portfolioStateRepository.findByPortfolioId(portfolioId).get();
            }else{
                this.portfolioState = portfolioStateRepository.save(new PortfolioState(portfolioId));
            }
        }
    }
}

@Entity
public class PortfolioState {

    public PortfolioState(){}

    public PortfolioState(int portfolioId){
        this.portfolioId = portfolioId;
    }

    @Id
    private int portfolioId;
}
```

Main class through CommandLineRunner below

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Portfolio p  = portfolioFactory.createPortfolio(1);
```